# Exception Handling in a gui application

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, unchecked

I'm a little lost on how to handle unchecked exceptions in my GUI application.

I e.g. have a function that saves a company newly created by the user in a (embedded) database.

The function for saving the newly created company throws 3 Exceptions:

`IllegalArgumentException`: If the company or a not null field is null (Manually checked and thrown).

`EntityExistException`: If the company (it's name) already exists. (Also manually checked and thrown).

`PersistenceException`: If something went wrong when trying to save. (Catched and rethrown).

The function that calls the `saveCompany` method catches all 3 Exceptions and then logs them and shows a dialog to the user that an error had occurred.

Im now wondering if i need to catch them at all? Or would it be ok to just let them run up to the `globalExceptionHandler` (where i can also look them)?
And im also wondering what my reaction should be?

Should I tell the user that there was an error and let the program run (cause other parts of the program should function properly) or should I tell him and then end the program (cause it's a programmers error that shouldn't be in there)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of the **IllegalArgumentException** you should catch the exception and tell the user to correct the data (do not print the stacktrace).

In case of the **EntityExistException** the user should be informed that the company already exists, and perhaps he or she should consider updating it.

When the user receives the **PersistenceException** they should be presented with a dialog window with the stacktrace (and perhaps other data relevant for the developer) and informed to submit a bug report.

Comment: I wouldn't actually display the stack trace to the user and I'd think about any anonymisation and/or secure transfer but yes this is reasonable.

Comment: Can i let the exceptions i can't directly handle like the PersistenceException run up to the globalExceptionHandler or should i catch them in the calling function like the other 2? Asking cause i have many functions that call functions which can throw such expections. So i wonder if i can spare some codelines (the code looks also cleaner with less catch blocks).

Comment: @LuGo Think that the customer be satisfied when seeing such a dialogue.

Comment: @Maja - Yes, capture them as late as possible, in your case in the globalExceptionHanlder. Thanks to this your code won't bloat.

Answer (score 4):

So the good news is you're asking all the right questions.

> Should i tell the user that there was an error and let the program run (cause other parts of the program should function properly) or should i tell him and then end the program (cause it's a programmers error that shouldn't be in there)?

That is a design question you need to think carefully about.  If it is a recoverable error and there is nothing the program can do to continue running, then the program should shutdown without the user having the option.  If part of the program must die but other parts may go one, the user should be informed.  If the user needs to fix some data so the program can run, the user should be informed as such.  Etc.  Yes, you are asking the right questions though, you just do actually have to think about them and be judicious.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion , do the following

`EntityExistException` : Let user know that entity already exists. Continue with the app.

`PersistenceException` and `IllegalArgumentException` : Give user a generic message, and stop the app.

I hope you see the difference in how the above two exceptions are being handled. One is something that can be caused and fixed by the user. The other is something the user cannot do anything about.

Comment: So should i catch PersistenceException and IllegalArgumentException in the calling function or should / can i let the GlobalExceptionHandler handle it?

Comment: It depends on a few things 1: If PersistenceException and IllegalArgumentException are thrown by any other parts of your code. 2: Do you want to handle all of them in the same way? 3 . Or do you want to handle these exceptions for saveCompany in a more localized way and then maybe throw a new Exception with a more descriptive message for the GlobalExceptionHandler to handle.